# Time in oracle with crossing over 0:00

Tags: oracle

can you help me please.

I'm use:

```
round((24 * 60 * (to_date(EndPick, 'HH24:MI') - to_date(StartPick, 'HH24:MI'))), 2) as WorkTime
```

All time EndPick bigger then StartPick. But we have a chance, what Start bigger where
estimate time interval if there is a crossing over 00:00 into the next date?

In relult for example:

> 3

(minutes)

Comment: This is a design problem, not a code problem. Store dates in DATE columns, not as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But we have a chance, what Start bigger where estimate time interval if there is a crossing over 00:00 into the next date?

Use a `CASE` expression and add a day if `startpick > endpick`:

```sql
SELECT round(
         (24 * 60 * (to_date(EndPick, 'HH24:MI')
                     + CASE
                       WHEN startpick > endpick
                       THEN INTERVAL '1' DAY
                       ELSE INTERVAL '0' DAY
                       END
                     - to_date(StartPick, 'HH24:MI')
                    )),
         2
       ) as WorkTime
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (startpick, endpick) AS
SELECT '00:00', '01:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '23:00', '00:00' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| WORKTIME |
| --- |
| 60 |
| 60 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fwUmSL-n)